# How to stop windows service created by install4j gracefully?

Tags: java, service, install4j

I have created a windows service from a big java application having lots of threads. Trouble is when I try to stop the service or restart it, sometimes it gives error message that service has failed to respond in timely manner. I have to then kill the process from task manager. Is there any way to handle such a situation in java code itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if your shutdown hooks are taking too long. As an administrator, you can [modify the time that Windows waits for a service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146092) but it's not something an application should do, even with elevated privileges. The only option is then to speed up your shutdown hooks.